# Running into issues when trying to randomize customer names for a testing database

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

I am currently trying to use SSIS to create a copy of a production database, rename it, and randomize customer information inside the customer table (first name and last name).  This may not be the best approach, but I have been trying to take all first names in the production database and add them to a single variable named FirstNames.  Also doing the same with LastNames.  I envisioned somehow breaking these variables up in a separate script component into some sort of a collection for each.  For each customer record coming through, I wanted to randomly select a first name from the FirstNames collection and replace the actual first name with this one.  I want to also do the same with the last name.  I have tried using string variables, and build them through a script component with a delimiter, and was just going to do a split on the delimiter in another script component to populate a collection, but the process of building the string variables was taking way too long, and I can understand that because we're talking about around 500,000 first names and last names.  I've tried using object variables, but I can't seem to figure out how to break everything out into a collection from there.

I need to know how to break out the object variable into a collection, or a more efficient approach to accomplish this task.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE a SET
    a.FirstName = (
        SELECT TOP 1 f.FirstName 
        FROM Customers f 
        WHERE f.CustomerId <> a.CustomerId
        ORDER BY NEWID()),
    a.LastName = (
        SELECT TOP 1 f.LastName 
        FROM Customers f 
        WHERE f.CustomerId <> a.CustomerId 
        ORDER BY NEWID()) 
from Customers a
```

I can't speak to the performance, but you can't get much simpler than that.
You'll get a different result every time you run it.

Hope that helps

Comment: You know, right after I posted for help, I thought about writing a stored procedure instead of trying to accomplish everything from within SSIS script components.  There are a few other fields I need to modify as well, but I am definitely using what you wrote for the first and last names.  Thanks for the help.